# entryComponents in Angular 4, how to listen event in parent element, emitted from entryComponnents

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a scenario where a component injected through entryComponents. In this case how Parent component can listen child component event(i.e. Emitted through eventemitter)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you injected it, that means you instantiated it yourself, then you can simply keep a reference on it and subscribe to the public `EventEmitter`.

After creating your `ComponentPortal` you attached it to a `PortalOutlet` or an `OverlayRef`. The return value of `attach` contains the instance of the injected component.

For example, let's say your component is named `SomeComponent` and has an `EventEmitter` named `someEventEmitter`:

```
let portal = new ComponentPortal(componentFactory.componentType);

let component = overlayRef.attach<SomeComponent>(portal);

component.instance.someEventEmitter.subscribe(() => {
  //Some code
});
```

Comment: @Rajsingh it's actually an answer, feel free to accept it if it solved your problem!

Comment: Yeah, you are right. But i did not try this solution, as i tried some other work around and that work for me.
That's  why did not talk about the solution. :)

Comment: Please, note, that in these cases Angular doesn't unsubscribe automatically from this EventEmitter

Comment: Yes @Pizzicato that implies do add some unsubscribe logic, ideally into the `ngOnDestroy` hook